# Flutter automatic settings from array

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create settings page from json. But first i'm checking if creating is working on static array:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:settings_ui/settings_ui.dart';

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
   bool lockInBackground = true;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tilearray = [{'name':'settings no 1'},{'name':'settings no 2'},{'name':'settings no 3'}];
    List<SettingsTile> tiles = [];
    log('{$tilearray}');
    tiles.add( SettingsTile.switchTile(
        initialValue: lockInBackground,
        onToggle: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            lockInBackground = value;
          });
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.phonelink_lock),
        title: Text('settings no 0')));
    tilearray.map((item) => log('test{$item.name}'));
    tilearray.map((item) => tiles.add( SettingsTile.switchTile(
        initialValue: lockInBackground,
        onToggle: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            lockInBackground = value;
          });
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.phonelink_lock),
        //title: Text(item['name']!))));
        title: Text('debug item'))));
   log('{$tiles}');
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Settings UI')),
      body: SettingsList(
        sections: [
          SettingsSection(
            title: Text('First Section'),
            tiles: tiles,
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

But the result is only one SettingsTile (Setting no 0)...

The comment I add to check if there's a problem with array item, but no. It looks like tilearray is empty.

It is strange that     `tilearray.map((item) => log('test{$item.name}'));` is empty too

Comment: Current format will break the context chain

Comment: Do not understand...

Comment: the ui update because because  you are putting everything inside build method, also everything is going to reassign . I will give an within 5min

Answer (score 1):

Follow current way.

try putting variable outside the build method or you can use initState

```dart
class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SettingsScreen> createState() => _SettingsScreenState();
}

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Map<String, bool> tilearray = {
    'settings no 1': false,
    'settings no 2': false,
    'settings no 3': false
  };

  List<SettingsTile> getTiles(BuildContext context) {
    List<SettingsTile> tiles = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.length; i++) {
      final question = tilearray.keys.elementAt(i);
      final value = tilearray.values.elementAt(i);
      tiles.add(SettingsTile.switchTile(
          initialValue: value,
          onToggle: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              tilearray[question] = value;
            });
          },
          leading: Icon(Icons.phonelink_lock),
          title: Text(question)));
    }
    ;
    return tiles;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Settings UI')),
      body: SettingsList(
        sections: [
          SettingsSection(
            title: Text('First Section'),
            tiles: getTiles(context),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope. I put it initState (and move List<SettingsTile> tiles = []; to Class) - but still the same - map doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide full but minimal widget that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: edited. But I put tilearray.map((item) => log('x{$item.name}')); and no log - it looks like tilearray is empty

Comment: The issue is with key

Comment: Try this simplification,

Comment: You changed tilearray - it will be a json result [{'name':'settings no 1','desc':'description'},{'name':'settings no 2','desc':'description'},{'name':'settings no 3','desc':'description'}], so I do not want to use key and value

Comment: do the way you like but on your structure you are already having key value for single map, cases like this i prefer using helper/adapter class to simplify the process

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I have to use

```
 for (final item in tilearray){
      log('x{$item}');
      tiles.add( SettingsTile.switchTile(
        initialValue: lockInBackground,
        onToggle: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            lockInBackground = value;
          });
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.phonelink_lock),
        //title: Text(item['name']!))));
        title: Text('element')));
      log('{$tiles}');
    }
  }
```

instead of

```
tilearray.map((item) =>
```

And as @Yeasin Sheikh wrote - have to move it to initState()